# Update conversation service workspace without changing workspace ID

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

Is there a way to update my conversation workspace without changing the workspace ID? I need to refresh my stage and prod workspaces every now and then. I use the Import option, but that creates a new workspace with a different workspace ID. This means I need to go and update the same in my app as well. I know I can potentially have it as an external environment variable. But ideally, I would want to avoid that as well. I just want a way to "update" an existing workspace without changing its ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the new Workspace API functionality. It will allow you to update a workspace programmatically without having to import.

I would recommend to test to see how it works before attempting to use it.

Comment: Thanks, will test it out.

Answer (score 0):

In the case I know two forms with Examples of IBM Developers.
.

**1st:** have the `.env` file, where you can add your `WORKSPACE_ID` and you don't need to be adding in the "Environment Variables" inside the Watson Conversation.

Check the `.env` example file with this [Conversation simple - Nodejs](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/.env.example)  and this [Conversation enhanced - Java](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery/blob/master/src/main/resources/server.env)

**Example:**

**Add the values inside `.env` file:**

```
# Environment variables
WORKSPACE_ID=<workspace-id>
CONVERSATION_USERNAME=<conversation-username>
CONVERSATION_PASSWORD=<conversation-password>
```

**2nd:** Adding the value of the `username`, `password`, and `workspace_id` variables inside the code.

The `password` and the `username` in the case is the **Service Credentials**, inside **Conversation Service**.

**Example:**

**Add your credentials and workspace_id - Conversation simple** (`app.js`):

```
var conversation = new Conversation({
  // If unspecified here, the CONVERSATION_USERNAME and CONVERSATION_PASSWORD env properties will be checked
  // After that, the SDK will fall back to the bluemix-provided VCAP_SERVICES environment property
  // username: '<username>',  // add your username here
  // password: '<password>',  // add your password here
  url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api',
  version_date: '2016-10-21',
  version: 'v1'
});

// Endpoint to be call from the client side
app.post('/api/message', function(req, res) {
  var workspace = process.env.WORKSPACE_ID || '<workspace-id>'; //if you dont added the value of workspace_id inside .env file, the app.js will try reconigze the value inside '<workspace-id>'
```

Comment: Both these need me to re-deploy my app which is worst. At least when I add environment variable I only need to re-start.

Comment: In this case I just edit the variable inside .env and restart the server :s but ok