# Inside Bluemix cloud, is there anyway to change the WORKSPACE_ID fast?

Tags: ibm-cloud, manifest, workspace, watson-conversation

After I made this demo app to work inside my account on Bluemix cloud
https://github.com/eGlobeBizCom/food-coach,
I create another workspace inside the above Watson Service Instance, and want to connect the above js code app with the second WORKSPACE_ID. Inside Bluemix cloud, in Runtime section, is there anyway to change the above ?WORKSPACE_ID fast? Or we have to change the WORKSPACE_ID manually in manifest.yml mentioned below
[Update conversation service workspace without changing workspace ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508848/update-conversation-service-workspace-without-changing-workspace-id/42556320#42556320)

After many searches on the web, no info can answer the above Q. Any suggestions are warmly welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case, you can:

**1.** Edit the workspace ID inside the [app.js](https://github.com/eGlobeBizCom/food-coach/blob/master/app.js#L61) file in line `#61`. If this link is really the reposity you are using.
But, dont miss replace the `username` and `password` from your Conversation Service, replace with `Service Credentials`.

Make sure if the workspace have this format if your replace `<workspace_id>` inside the `workspace` variable:

```
var workspace = "4235254-546563g-sfgsg-sgs-ggsfsegs" //test
var workspace = '4235254-546563g-sfgsg-sgs-ggsfsegs' //test
```

**2.** You can see the line have the code: `process.env.WORKSPACE_ID`. This is because the repository use `dotenv` package, you can simple edit the `.env` file and replace the value of the `WORKSPACE_ID`;

**3.** You can simple add the Enviroment Variables in the IBM Bluemix too! Try:

[image]

In this case, you will click in the Runtime, and you will see the "Enviroment Variables". Replace the **name** with WORKSPACE_ID and the **value** with your `workspace_id`. After, restart your application.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. We will experiment the above and inform you they work in our account or not.

Comment: We experimented this "In this case, you will click in the Runtime, and you will see the "Enviroment Variables". Replace the name with WORKSPACE_ID and the value with your workspace_id. After, restart your application.", it works correctly.

Comment: If this help please mark the question to help other if they have the same problem